# Adobe command line to encrypt files

Tags: command-line, security, pdf, batch-file

I have the task to find a command line to use a batch file to encrypt pdf files.

There a pool of pdf files which should be converted in secure pdf files (all with the same password). I would like to use a batch file to do this so I need the command line command.

I haven´t found a solution for this by searching for it. Maybe here is some mastermind which can help me.

Comment: Have you tried Googling for something wildly obscure like `pdf batch encrypt command line` perhaps?

Comment: I did. But it seemed that there a only command line commands for opening and printing pdf files not to secure them